# How to authentication with login form in yii framework

Tags: php, authentication, yii, syntax-error

Hello friends i am beginner in yii framework and i wanna to create login form with authentication but i have this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::model() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro_c\protected\components\UserIdentity.php on line 47

UserIdentity.php

```
    public function authenticate()
    {


    $users = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));


            if(!isset($users[$this->username]))
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            elseif($users[$this->username]!==$this->password)
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            else
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            return !$this->errorCode;
      }
   }

    ?>
```

UserController.php

```
    class UserController extends Controller
    {

    public function actionIndex()
    {
            // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
            // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
            $this->render('index');
    }


    public function actionLogin()
    {
            $model=new User;


            if(isset($_POST['User']))
            {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                    // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
                    if($model->validate() && $model->login())
                            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
            // display the login form
            $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
    }


    public function actionLogout()
    {
            Yii::app()->user->logout();
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
    }
   }
  ?>
```

User.php

```
    /**
      * LoginForm class.
      * LoginForm is the data structure for keeping
      * user login form data. It is used by the 'login' action of 'SiteController'.
      */
    class User extends CFormModel
    {
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe;

    private $_identity;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * The rules state that username and password are required,
     * and password needs to be authenticated.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
            return array(
                    // username and password are required
                    array('username, password', 'required'),
                    // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
                    array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
                    // password needs to be authenticated
                    array('password', 'authenticate'),
            );
    }

    /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
            return array(
                    'rememberMe'=>'Remember me next time',
            );
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates the password.
     * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
     */
    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
            if(!$this->hasErrors())
            {
                    $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
                    if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
                            $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
            }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
     * @return boolean whether login is successful
     */
    public function login()
    {
            if($this->_identity===null)
            {
                    $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
                    $this->_identity->authenticate();
            }
            if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
            {
                    $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
                    Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
                    return true;
            }
            else
                    return false;
    }
   }
  ?>
```

---

when i use this code in UserIdentity

```
    $users=array(
        // username => password
        'demo'=>'demo',
        'admin'=>'admin',

    );
```

return true
but when i using

```
     $users = Pi::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
```

return me this error

```
     Fatal error: Call to undefined method Pi::model() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro_c\protected\components\UserIdentity.php on line 47
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a model called User that is of the type CFormModel (it is a form model). But you are trying to access User::model()->findByAttributes (a database model) that is used for the type CActiveModel. You should rename your class User to something else. Here for example, your User class is called UserIdentity.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

You have to make quite a few changes to your code to work. Just see the Yii blog demo to get you to the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be on the right path, but Yii seems to be unable to find the User class.

You could manually import the class, or better still, automatically load this using the 'import' directive in the file protected/config/main.

This tells yii to load all models in *protected/models/* directory, assuming that is where the User.php class file resides.

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```